# Getting correct audio in streaming but chunks are playing multiple times

Tags: typescript, audio, next.js13, audio-streaming

```js
const handleTextToSpeech = async () => {
    if (message === "") return;

    const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/synthesize";

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "text": message,
        "voice": "final_Either.mp4",
        "rate": 1,
      }),
    });
    
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    
    const reader = response.body!.getReader();
    const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || (window as any).webkitAudioContext)();
    let source: AudioBufferSourceNode | undefined;
    let connected = false;
    let bufferSet = false; // Flag to check if buffer is set
    
    const chunks: Uint8Array[] = []; // Store received chunks
    
    while (true) {
      const { done, value } = await reader.read();
    
      if (done) {
        break;
      }
    
      chunks.push(value); // Store the received chunk
    
      if (!source) {
        source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        source.onended = () => {
          // Reset the source node and connected flag when it ends
          source = undefined;
          connected = false;
          bufferSet = false; // Reset the buffer set flag
        };
      }
    
      if (!connected && !bufferSet) {
        try {
          // Attempt to decode the accumulated audio data
          const audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(concatenateChunks(chunks));
          source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    
          // Connect and start only if it's the first time
          source.connect(audioContext.destination);
          source.start();
          connected = true;
          bufferSet = true; // Set the buffer set flag
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error decoding audio data:', error);
          // Handle decoding error
        }
      }
    }
    
    // Utility function to concatenate audio chunks
    function concatenateChunks(chunks: Uint8Array[]): ArrayBuffer {
      const totalLength = chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => acc + chunk.length, 0);
      const result = new Uint8Array(totalLength);
      let offset = 0;
    
      for (const chunk of chunks) {
        result.set(chunk, offset);
        offset += chunk.length;
      }
    
      return result.buffer;
    }
};
```

In the above code I am getting audio in streaming from server. I want to stream that audio in frontend. I am playing that audio but in chunks and same chunks playing multiple times like an array of array looping through everytime when new chunks add.

I want to know if there are any better way to do this with code.